# Windows 10: кэширование часто загружаемых файлов в памяти?

Tags: windows, windows-10, файловая-система

Я занимаюсь разработкой приложений для Windows и под Windows. Во время работы приходится по многу раз запускать одно и то же приложение. Приложение запускается заметное время и приходится ждать его загрузки прежде чем начать отладку. Хочется как-то ускорить загрузку.
Оперативной памяти достаточно много - 16 гигабайт. Один из вариантов - создать RAM диск и расположить приложение на нём. Но приложение так же загружает кучу других файлов, которые тянет из разных папок на диске, в том числе системных. Складывать все зависимости на RAM диск каждый раз при его запуске как-то не очень удобно.

Существует ли возможность кэшировать часто загружаемые файлы в оперативной памяти для ускорения их загрузки? Какая-нибудь встроенная опция или стороннее приложение?

Оптимизировать приложение на предмет ускорения загрузки не вариант, так как я работаю над приложением не один, а в команде и над ускорением загрузки надо работать всем. Загрузка занимает менее минуты. Пользователь загружает приложение 1-2 раза в день(а мне приходится это делать до 50 раз в день) и кто тому же релизную сборку, а не дебаговую. Так что усорение загрузки точно не является приоритетом для руководства и заказчиков.

Comment: Если все файлы открываются только на чтение, то можно написать минимальную программу, которая будет заниматься только тем, что читает все необходимые файлы, и держать ее запущенной всё время.

Comment: Windows 10 и так кэширует читаемые файлы в памяти, причем отводит под это почти всю свободную память - это хорошо видно по task manager.

Comment: А как это можно понять по task manager? В нём вся память расписана по процессам и они собственно большую часть выделенной памяти и занимают. Если приложение закрыть, то память занятая им освобождается.